# rethinkdb changesfeed in express with socket.io displaying [object object]

Tags: javascript, object, express, socket.io, rethinkdb

I'm using express.js, rethinkdb, thinky, socket.io. Trying to notify the index page of any changes that happens in the db. So I use rethinkdb changesfeed (and I can see the updates in console.log) but the cursor/feed is showing object object instead of the data.

When I pass the feed results to the socket.emit, it displays [object object]?
I read and implemented the code that comes from the rethinkdb blog (https://www.rethinkdb.com/blog/cats-of-instagram/) but it is not working.

Please scroll down to the bottom with socket.io header

App.js

```
 var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var r = require('rethinkdb');

// ***********  Thinky code*********************//
var changeStream = require("rethinkdb-change-stream");
var thinky = require('thinky')()
var type = thinky.type;
var r = thinky.r;

//thinky model
var User = thinky.createModel('User', {
      author: type.string()
});

/*
User.changes().then(function (feed) {
    feed.each(function (error, doc) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            process.exit(1);
        }

        if (doc.isSaved() === false) {
            console.log("The following document was deleted:");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
        }
        else if (doc.getOldValue() == null) {
            console.log("A new document was inserted:");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
        }
        else {
            console.log("A document was updated.");
            console.log("Old value:");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(doc.getOldValue()));
            console.log("New value:");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
        }
    });
}).error(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
});

*/
//*********End Thinky Code ******************//




// Mongodb Example http://www.guru99.com/node-js-mongodb.html
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/EmployeeDB';


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
//attach socket server to express server so it interacts with clients requests and responses
app.io = require('socket.io')();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


/*    )))))))))))))))) socket.io Header (((((((((((((((((((    */

    app.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        r.connect(host = 'localhost', port = 28015, db = 'test').then(function (conn) {
            this.conn = conn;
            return r.table("User").changes().run(this.conn).then(function (cursor) {
                cursor.each(function (err, item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    //if (item && item.new_val)
                       socket.emit("message-from-server", { greeting: item });
                });
            })
        });
        // socket.emit("message-from-server", { greeting: "Say whatever here- it will show on the index page"});
    });


  module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
console.log(item);
//if (item && item.new_val)
socket.emit("message-from-server", { greeting: item });
```

This tells me that `item` is probably an object so when you pass it to the web api to add to the DOM it renders the object reference `[object Object]` because its expecting a string (not an object).  So you can pull out the info you want from `item` using `.` syntax for objects or `[<index>]` syntax for arrays, or you could do something like `item.toString()` to attempt to turn the whole thing into a string.  It really depends on the structure of `item` and how you are adding it to the DOM.  You could do it on the client side or do it before it's emitted from your server.

Comment: Thank you J3py.  I was able to get it to work with your explanation.

Comment: @Marco Great!  Glad I could help :)